# Add the ID property of headings as the `name` attribute in the HTML export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, org-link, hyperlinks

E.g., suppose I have this heading:

```
* some heading
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       6d4e4087-4b74-4c74-8195-19b4ccd3e8fe
:END:
```

I like the exported HTML element to have the attribute

```html
name="ID-6d4e4087-4b74-4c74-8195-19b4ccd3e8fe"
```

This will make cross-file ID links work when exporting org files as HTML, as the links have the ID as an anchor already: `...#ID-6d4e4087-4b74-4c74-8195-19b4ccd3e8fe`.

Comment: I have sent a [patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2022-10/msg00820.html) to the mailing list that solves this problem.